# Subquery between three tables using Northwind database with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, northwind

1. Table `[Orders] : OrderID(Primary Key), CustomerID`
2. Table `[Order Details] : OrderID(Primary Key), ProductID(Primary Key), Discount`
3. Table `[Customers] : CustomerID[Primary Key]`

With these three tables, I want to query `productID` with highest discount for each `CustomerID`. I need column for `ProductID`, `CustomerID` and `Discount`. How can I solve this problem? All kinds of helps are really appreciated.

Following script I have tried :

```
select ProductID, a.customerID, 
    (select MAX(discount) 
     from [Order Details] 
     where a.CustomerID=c.customerID
    )
from Orders a 
    join [Order Details]
        on a.OrderID=[Order Details].OrderID 
    join Customers c
        on a.CustomerID=c.CustomerID    
order by customerID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will return to you the productid with maximum discount for each customer. Please note that if for specific customer, you have more than one product that might have the max discount, I you want to return them, then you need to replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `DENSE_RANK()`

```
  WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT ProductID, 
           o.CustomerID,
           Discount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.CustomerID ORDER BY Discount DESC) Row_num
    FROM [Order Details] od INNER JOIN Orders o
         ON od.OrderID= o.OrderID
    )
    SELECT ProductID, 
           CustomerID,
         Discount
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Row_num = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a million. but can I ask one more question? I got error message like this : "The multi-part identifier "o.CustomerID" could not be bound.
Invalid column name 'Discount'." How can I solve this?

Comment: @bizcon, I have updated the answer to fix these errors and added Max function on Discount in the CTE